# One ASP.Net application on IBM Cloud - One or more MongoDB's?

Tags: mongodb, ibm-cloud

I have an ASP.NET application running IBM Cloud, and I have a MongoDB instance created, and my application is deployed in my development-space, and bound to the MongoDB(alias). All working fine.
Now, I have also created a production-space, and want to deploy the application there, after having verified it in Dev.
But - do I really have to create another MongoDB - and pay for 2 instances, or can I somehow share one instance (with security seperating that dev cant access prod)?
Or what is best practice in this case?

Any advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is your call.  The connection string to the mongodb will work from both dev and prod.  I would recommend having two mongodb instances.  A separate dev mongodb will allow development to work in isolation both functionally, performance and security.